# How to make use of Existing Window to install a Curtain

Tags: windows, curtain-rail

I've moved to a new apartment(in USA) where in my bedroom I have a window(obviously with horizontal blinds). It is in a place where people from outside can see through the blinds. So I wanted to install a curtain to protect my privacy.

[image: Screenshoot]

Is it possible to install the curtain to the blind holder? If yes, any product sources/information is much appreciated. If not, do I need to start from scratch: measuring/fixing rod/attach curtain?

Any information would be really helpful.

Comment: the bar at the top is just clipped into its holders, so you cannot put too much weight on the blind. do a proper installation of curtains.......... `If not, do I need to start from scratch` what does this mean?

Comment: Have you tried to turn the blinds down instead of up? Some work better one direction and others the other direction. Otherwise, measure the window, get the rod you like (usually come with the hardware to install) and the curtains you like. Other option is to replace the blinds with a privacy or darkening kind.

Comment: @jsotola I mean: measurements, drilling the wall, attahing brackets, fixing rods and curtains.

Comment: @JeffCates I tried both the ways, unfortunately as my apt was in the first floor, no way I can have these blinds to work completely. I might need to do the drill work man!! damnit.

Comment: Check with the apartment owner before installing the curtains - they may not look too favorably on you putting holes in the walls. They may also use that as an excuse to withhold some or all of your damage deposit when you move out.

Comment: At the top of the window is a header and on each side a stud called a cripple and a king using regular screws is how I fasten curtains above and to the sides.

Answer (score 2):

I would speak first with the landlord (as apartment to me implies that you are renting) to get the OK to install the curtain. Once you have that you would want to install the curtain rod on the wall surface above the window and have it extend beyond the width of the window on each side.

There are a plethora of curtain rod assembly styles that you can choose from. Some are easier to install than others so look at that aspect so you know just what you are getting into before you purchase.

Note that on normally wood framed construction buildings you have about three inches of space to the side of the window and at least that much above the window where you can screw the curtain rod brackets through the sheet rock and into the wood framing. This provides the most secure mounting.

If the places where you need to mount the curtain rod brackets is just a hollow wall area then you will have a bit bigger job of installing the brackets in a secure manner. The normal cheap wall anchors like below are really junk and not recommended. Instead use an anchor like that in the second picture.

not recommended:

[image]

recommended:

[image]

[image]

[image]